# Should I use compare_exchange_weak(or strong) when check atomic<bool> variable is set?

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++14, compare-and-swap

Below code is an usage example of `atomic<bool>` from book c++ concurrency in action chapter 5.
Why do they use compare_exchange_weak for checking b is set and why do they use `!expected`  inside while loop ?

```
bool expected=false;
extern atomic<bool> b; // set somewhere else
while(!b.compare_exchange_weak(expected,true) && !expected);
```

Can I change above code to simple code like below ?

```
extern atomic<bool> b; // set somewhere else
while(!b.load());
```

Comment: Their code sets the flag to true. Looks mostly equivalent to `b = true;` without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that is a confusing piece of code. Firstly the obvious point, the compare_exchange_weak version (might) change the value of the underlying atomic value. b.load() does not, so they are not equivalent.

To explain...

> while(!b.compare_exchange_weak(expected,true) && !expected);

b.compare_exchange_weak(expected,true) says

> if b is false make it true, otherwise set expected = b(true)

Now you might ask, why does the code check the value after the exchange?
It is checking to see if another thread has already set the value. which causes the loop to exit. But then, if the code exits no matter what the value of b, why the loop?

The loop is there because the weak-version of the function can just do nothing (for no reason).

So this code is equivalent to

> b.compare_exchange_strong(expected,true);

I'm not sure why the author didn't write it this way, but I'm missing the context for it. I'd certainly have problems with someone who put that in production code, without a nice explanatory comment above it!

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange for details.
See https://newbedev.com/understanding-std-atomic-compare-exchange-weak-in-c-11 for a similar discusion

Comment: You mean spurious wake up. So, what about while(!b.compare_exchange_weak(expected,true) && !b.load()); ? Isn't it more clear ?

Comment: An atomic load is potentially more expensive, so I'd say functionally this is true, but slower. I'm not sure it aids understanding though. In general, prefer a std-lib function if possible. It's possible that the author was avoiding the use of this function for some reason, but if so they should have explained it.